# Javascript working on chrome but not on IE-11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

So I found a function that exports an html table into csv using javascript. For some reason it works perfectly on chrome but not on internet explorer v11.
Any help would be appreciated!

```
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;

        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }}
```

Comment: using things not supported by IE11 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility Error messages in console probably pointed you there.

Comment: *"Javascript working on chrome but not on IE-11"*... a.k.a. real world.

Comment: Have you used F12 to check if there's any error in console in IE11? And I'm in favor of what @epascarello said, default function parameters is not supported in IE.

Comment: Note that even when you will fix this default-parameter thing, your code has actually a real flow (as opposed to something a transpiler could handle): the Blob you do generate in the IE if block will have all its space characters replaced as the UTF8 `%20` characters. This will do no good to your csv data. Do the percent encoding only in the dataURL case, or even better, don't do it at all and use a Blob even for anchor download, you'll be able to save bigger dataset.